# Page freeze on using links

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have different pages and the data needed for the page to loaded is present in database. i wanted to automate the code for import, creating the list and also creating routes, the drawer items to be selected and highlighted as per the url and even when the page is reloaded manually. I am fairly new to React.Please help. Thanks in advance

```
// NavBar.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppBar, Drawer, Toolbar, Typography, List, ListItem, ListItemText, ListSubheader } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link, Route, Routes, useResolvedPath, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  const resolvedLocation = useResolvedPath();
  const location = resolvedLocation.pathname;

  // Array of categories and pages retrieved from the database
  const categories = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Sales',
      pages: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Sales 1', path: '/sales1', component: 'Sales1', componentLocation: './path/to/Sales1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Sales 2', path: '/sales2', component: 'Sales2', componentLocation: './path/to/Sales2' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Marketing',
      pages: [
        { id: 3, name: 'Marketing 1', path: '/marketing1', component: 'Marketing1', componentLocation: './path/to/Marketing1' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Marketing 2', path: '/marketing2', component: 'Marketing2', componentLocation: './path/to/Marketing2' },
      ],
    },
    // Add more categories and pages as needed
  ];

  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [pageComponents, setPageComponents] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the page index based on the current location
    const currentPageIndex = categories.flatMap(category => category.pages)
      .findIndex(page => location === page.path);
      
    if (currentPageIndex !== -1) {
      setPageIndex(currentPageIndex + 1);
    }
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Dynamically import the page components
    const importPageComponents = async () => {
      const components = {};
      for (const category of categories) {
        for (const page of category.pages) {
          try {
            const component = await import(`${page.componentLocation}`);
            components[page.component] = component.default;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Failed to import component "${page.componentLocation}":`, error);
          }
        }
      }
      setPageComponents(components);
    };

    importPageComponents();
  }, [categories]);

  // Render the page component dynamically
  const renderPageComponent = (component) => {
    const Component = pageComponents[component];
    return Component ? <Component /> : null;
  };

  // Navigation bar code goes here
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar>
        {/* App bar content */}
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer>
        <List>
          {categories.map(category => (
            <div key={category.id}>
              <ListSubheader>{category.title}</ListSubheader>
              {category.pages.map(page => (
                <ListItem
                  key={page.id}
                  component={Link}
                  to={page.path}
                  button
                  selected={location === page.path}
                >
                  <ListItemText primary={`${page.id}. ${page.name}`} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Routes>
        {categories.flatMap(category => category.pages).map(page => (
          <Route
            key={page.id}
            path={page.path}
            element={renderPageComponent(page.component)}
          />
        ))}
      </Routes>
      {/* Rest of the navigation bar */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

i have no clue of what is happening. But I am sure that there is infinite loop being created and I am unable to solve the issue. When I click on the links, just the page stops proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your code formatter doesn't offer you this, but this is the first thing I have when I copy and paste your code into vs code.

[image: suggestion off vs code]

Be careful with using constant arrays like this. The node will recreate your array at each rendering. And yes, as you mentioned, this leads to an infinite loop.

```js
const categories = [
...
```

Wrap initialization of categories to useMemo hook, for example